# Sphinx autodoc functions within module

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, docstring, autodoc

I am just getting started with sphinx and willing to learn.

I would like to break up my various functions into different sections within my `index.rst` file. So each function has it's own header.

So for example if I have a python file named `test.py` and within that file I have 2 functions:

```
def foo():
    """This prints bar"""
    print("bar")

def bar():
    """This prints foo"""
    print("foo")
```

How could I within the `index.rst` separate the 2 functions within my test.py file?

```
:mod:`test` -- foo
.. automodule:: test.foo
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance: 
:mod:`test` -- bar
.. automodule:: test.bar
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

If I can figure out how to separate the functions so it looks cleaner in the `index.html` that would be great! As it is now the output is not very clean if I just run the following below:

```
:mod:`test` -- these are my functions
--------------------------------------------
.. automodule:: test
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`autofunction`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html?highlight=autofunction#directive-autofunction). Like this:

```
The test module
===============

The test module contains...

.. currentmodule:: test

The foo function
----------------

.. autofunction:: foo

The bar function
----------------

.. autofunction:: bar
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it automatically? instead of listing each function? So it lists all the functions that have a docstring? like `.. automodule::` does?

Comment: There is no built-in way to do it.