# How to create a horizontal line and white space between function signatures in Sphinx autodoc

Tags: python, formatting, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I have found sphinx options for most of what I want to do, but I can't see how to inject white space and a horizontal line between function signatures when using autodoc.

Here's what autodoc produces:

```
get_all_edges(network=None, base_url='http://localhost:1234/v1')
   docstring for get_all_edges

get_all_nodes(network=None, base_url='http://localhost:1234/v1')
   docstring for get_all_nodes

get_edge_count(network=None, base_url='http://localhost:1234/v1')
   docstring for get_edge_count
```

Here's what I'm trying to get:

```
get_all_edges(network=None, base_url='http://localhost:1234/v1')
   docstring for get_all_edges

   ------------------------------------------------------------

get_all_nodes(network=None, base_url='http://localhost:1234/v1')
   docstring for get_all_nodes

   ------------------------------------------------------------

get_edge_count(network=None, base_url='http://localhost:1234/v1')
   docstring for get_edge_count
```

... or something close to this. I'm not passionate about whether the last function signature has a trailing separator. Maybe this is simple, but I'm not seeing it. Thanks!

FYI, here are the autodoc directives that produced my function signatures:

```
PyCy3.networks module
---------------------

.. automodule:: PyCy3.networks
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Comment: Sphinx is a documentation system that divides sementic and format as good as possible (as it should be). In general it is not a good idea to add format by content. If you want to change the formatting adapt the templates and/or stylesheets.

Comment: With `autofunction` instead of `automodule`, it is possible to achieve what you want.  Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19280972/407651

Answer (score 8):

As it turns out, this wasn't so hard ... after doing a day of research. :)

The key insights were:

1. autodoc creates HTML so that each function has class="function"
2. class "function" isn't defined anywhere ... it's a hook for just
   this purpose
3. it's possible to define "function" using a combination of _template
   and _static folders in my doc folder

The inspiration for #3 was here: [Modifying content width of the Sphinx theme 'Read the Docs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211695/modifying-content-width-of-the-sphinx-theme-read-the-docs)

(I *am* using readthedocs, so I'm not completely sure this will work with command line sphinx.)

In my case, the "docs" folder has all of my sphinx files. I created new sub-folders: "_templates" and "_static/css".

In _templates, I created a new file "layout.html":

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% set css_files = css_files + [ "_static/css/functions.css" ] %}
```

In _static/css, I created a new file "functions.css":

```
.function {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #d0d0d0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

So, layout.html extends the default layout.html and injects my new css.

I think autodoc creates other hooks for this purpose (e.g., sig-name, sig-paren and sig-param) for the various elements of a function signature. You can discover this for yourself by using Chrome's page source inspector in the web page debugger.

Comment: Here's another excellent [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079200/how-do-i-set-up-custom-styles-for-restructuredtext-sphinx-readthedocs-etc/32079202#32079202) for how to do things like this

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! In my case, the folders `_templates` and `_static` already existed, but within the `source` folder inside the `docs` folder. I added the `css` subfolder to `_static` and the files you suggested to them and everything worked perfectly.